# Plotting two fitted curves in the same plot (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, plot, curve-fitting

I am trying to plot two fitted curves using two-term gauss model on Matlab. While plotting the fitted curves individually, the plots show the entire fitted curve but when I combine both the fitted curve in a single plot only a part of the curves is being displayed the rest is being cut off.

code:

```
% Data     
X1 = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]';
Y1 = [0.004 0.010 0.025 0.036 0.057 0.061 0.044 0.032 0.039 0.024 0.020]';
X2 = X1;
Y2 = [0.012 0.018 0.032 0.046 0.067 0.071 0.054 0.042 0.025 0.019 0.011]';

[p1,p2,p3] = deal(0.04, 3.5, 1.6);
[q1,q2,q3] = deal(0.03, 5.8, 4.02);

% Options
opt = fitoptions('method','NonlinearLeastSquares','Lower',[-Inf -Inf 0]);
ind1 = isfinite(X1) & isfinite(Y1);
ind2 = isfinite(X2) & isfinite(Y2);

set(opt,'Startpoint',[p1 p2 p3 q1 q2 q3]);
typ = fittype('gauss2');

% Fit 
cf1 = fit(X1(ind1),Y1(ind1),typ,opt);
cf2 = fit(X2(ind2),Y2(ind2),typ,opt);

figure(1)
plot(cf1,'fit',0.95);

figure(2)
plot(cf2,'fit',0.95);

% Problem lies here while combining the two plots 
figure(3)
hold on
plot(cf1,'fit',0.95);
plot(cf2,'fit',0.95);
```

- How do I show the two curves in the same plot?.
- How do I make the fitted curves to start at the point x=0, y=0.02 without altering most of its original shape?

Comment: try `plot(cf1,cf2)`. That should plot both curves in the same plot. That works as well if you collect data and want to plot the data and the fitted curve in one plot 'plot(fitobject, data_x, data_y)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
figure(3)
hold on
plot(cf1,'fit',0.95);
plot(cf2,'fit',0.95);
```

by

```
figure(3)
plot(cf1,'fit',0.95);
hold on
plot(cf2,'fit',0.95);
```

What is happening? The hold on command already fixes the axis of the plot. It seems the fit plot then uses this axis to determine its plot range. If you plot before the hold, the fit plot determines its plot range automatically.

Comment: How do I force the fitted curves to start at a desired point?. For example, if I want the fitted curves to start at y=0.02?

Comment: Not in this way, sorry if you got me wrong. I am looking for both the fitted curves to start at the point x=0, y=0.02 while retaining most of its shape. A slight change in its shape at initial points, for example from x=0 to x=1, is acceptable.